# How good is (and will be) Postgresql's Hstore compared to a document DB?

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, nosql

I am interested as it comes with a robust ACID DB **and** it is schemaless, the best of both worlds?

How is it compared to a document DB like Mongo which promises very high performance and **full secondary indexes**?

I am talking in terms of performance, indexing of values and most importantly ad-hoc query capability. And does it enchance/ sacrifice features present in relational tables?

Comment: I never used MongoDB but I'm *very* impressed with the speed of Postgres' hstore type.